# Is there a negative dimensional object similar to a black hole / singularity?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, singularities

My view of negative dimensional objects is one where different objects are all stacked up one on top of the other within the same co-ordinates. Multiple objects may occupy the same space in negative dimensions. It seems to me that just because I can't make sense of the dimensionality doesn't mean it doesn't exist.
I'm wondering if there are any real negative dimensional objects in space. Why believe in just singularities?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52176/2451

Answer (score 1):

You're free to extend the definition of the word "dimension" in any way you want, as long as you have a rigorous mathematical definition for your proposed extension.  But the generally excepted definition of "dimension" is "the number of independent coordinates you need to list in order to uniquely specify a location within the space," and under this definition a negative dimensionality doesn't make any sense.